# VirtualBox Ubuntu 20.04 VM Booting to Terminal After Power-Off

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, gui

I have been working on an Ubuntu 20.04 VM for a project for about a week now. Between work sessions I have been just saving the machine state (not fully shutting the VM down) and resuming. For the first time today I went ahead and did the power off machine option, but when I try to re-open it all I can get is the terminal screen. I had been enjoying the GUI for the last week, and admittedly, this is the first time I had fully restarted it. I found a similar post that recommended running a few commands in the terminal, but none of those options worked. Additionally, it might be notable that if I try "sudo apt-get update" it fails. Outside of performing the first full shutdown, I didn't touch any of the settings. Any help or recommendations is appreciated.

Comment: type "sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target"

Comment: I get "plymouth-start.service" as output